# Spectral separability

Tags: spectral-analysis

I'm new in the forum and with R.. 
I have already read a post about this topic (spectral separability: Jeffries-Matusita, Divergence and Bhattacharryya index), but i need calculate a spectral separability of 14 different samples and each one has 25 spectral measures...Can I just compare two to two or can I write a cicle (or some code)  that allow me compare all samples togheter?

I tried with the follow codes, that somebody wrote in another post...but here there are just 2 samples, and when I tried to create the "P"(halfsumer of cv) he gives me the error: nn-conformable arrays and I can't go away....

separability.measures <- function ( Vector.1 , Vector.2 ) {

## convert vectors to matrices in case they are not

Matrix.1 <- as.matrix (Vector.1)
  Matrix.2 <- as.matrix (Vector.2)

## define means

mean.Matrix.1 <- mean ( Matrix.1 )
mean.Matrix.2 <- mean ( Matrix.2 )

## define difference of means

mean.difference <- mean.Matrix.1 - mean.Matrix.2

## define covariances for supplied matrices

cv.Matrix.1 <- cov ( Matrix.1 )
cv.Matrix.2 <- cov ( Matrix.2 )

## define the halfsum of cv's as "p"

p <- ( cv.Matrix.1 + cv.Matrix.2 ) / 2

## --%<------------------------------------------------------------------------

## calculate the Bhattacharryya index

bh.distance <- 0.125 *t ( mean.difference ) * p^ ( -1 ) * mean.difference +
0.5 * log (det ( p ) / sqrt (det ( cv.Matrix.1 ) * det ( cv.Matrix.2 )
)
)

## --%<------------------------------------------------------------------------

## calculate Jeffries-Matusita

## following formula is bound between 0 and 2.0

jm.distance <- 2 * ( 1 - exp ( -bh.distance ) )

## also found in the bibliography:

## jm.distance <- 1000 * sqrt (   2 * ( 1 - exp ( -bh.distance ) )   )

## the latter formula is bound between 0 and 1414.0

## --%<------------------------------------------------------------------------

## calculate the divergence

## trace (is the sum of the diagonal elements) of a square matrix

trace.of.matrix <- function ( SquareMatrix ) {
sum ( diag ( SquareMatrix ) ) }

## term 1

divergence.term.1 <- 1/2 * trace.of.matrix (( cv.Matrix.1 - cv.Matrix.2 ) * 
( cv.Matrix.2^ (-1) - cv.Matrix.1^ (-1) )
)

## term 2

divergence.term.2 <- 1/2 * trace.of.matrix (( cv.Matrix.1^ (-1) + cv.Matrix.2^ (-1) ) *
( mean.Matrix.1 - mean.Matrix.2 ) *
t ( mean.Matrix.1 - mean.Matrix.2 )
)

## divergence

divergence <- divergence.term.1 + divergence.term.2

## --%<------------------------------------------------------------------------

## and the transformed divergence

transformed.divergence  <- 2 * ( 1 - exp ( - ( divergence / 8 ) ) )
indices <- data.frame(
jm=jm.distance,bh=bh.distance,div=divergence,tdiv=transformed.divergence)
return(indices)
}

Comment: Needs some formatting cleanup, but is a good, and impo, a cv relevant question.